# can i search from multi database in my model using django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

i have this code and work perfect .. but i want search in all my models how to do that ?

any idea for that ?

mycode

Models.py:

```
class OpratingSystems(models.Model):
# def etc .. 
class AndroidGames(models.Model):
# def etc ..
class Antivirus(models.Model):
# def etc ..
class AndroidApks(models.Model):
# def etc ..
class PCgames(models.Model):
# def etc ..
class PCprogram(models.Model):
# def etc ..
class Homepage(models.Model):
# def etc ..
```

Views.py :

```
   def search(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        query= request.GET.get('q')
        submitbutton= request.GET.get('submit')

        if query is not None:
            lookups= Q(name__icontains=query) | Q(app_contect__icontains=query) | Q(page_url__icontains=query) | Q(app_image__icontains=query)

            results= Homepage.objects.filter(lookups).distinct()


            context={'results': results,
                     'submitbutton': submitbutton}

            return render(request, 'html_file/enterface.html', context)

        else:
            return render(request, 'html_file/enterface.html')

    else:
        return render(request, 'html_file/enterface.html')
```

html page :

```
     {% if submitbutton == 'Search' and request.GET.q != '' %}
 {% if results %}
 <h1> <small> Results for </small><b>{{ request.GET.q }}</b> : </h1>
 <br/><br/>

 {% for result in results %}
 <label id="label_main_app"> <img id="img_main_app_first_screen" src="{{result.app_image.url}}" alt="no image found !" height="170" width="165" > {{result.name}} <br><br> <p id="p_size_first_page"> {{result.app_contect}} <br> <br> <a href="{{ result.page_url }}" type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><big> See More & Download </big>  </a> </p>
  </label>


 {% endfor %}
 {% else %}
 <h3> No results for this search </h3>
 {% endif %}
 {% endif %}
```

this was my code and work in Homeoage model so how to use all model ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be by using the filter() methods and then combine all queries in a single with itertools.chain

```
if query is not None:

   query1 =Model1.objects.filter(title__icontains=query)
   query2 = Model2.objects.filter(modelfield__icontains=query)
....

#now you can combine all queries with this chain method

   from itertools import chain
   results= list(chain(query1,query2...)
```

Comment: thanks , i will try it 
but one questions , when i import chain and do this , i will keep all rest other of my code in view right?

Comment: You do this within your search function

Comment: yes i did this your answer  helped me  thanks again bro

Comment: can i ask you ,, i want add Paginator to my search how to do that with chain